# subset dataframe and plot all the subsets with a loop [R]

Tags: r

Im working with a dataframe with 8 useful variables, the idea of the code its to plot 4 variables (3 on y axis and a common x axis). The data frame looks like this:

[It has like 6500 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSMtJ.png)

I want to subset the data.frame from the file column, and then plot LogP as a x axis and Temperature, RH and ozone as y axis.
I tried using subset inside the plot function but didnt go well. I used this code for the plot with one of the original files, but no idea how to include the subset

```
> plot(DataOzono$LogP, DataOzono$Temperature, axes= F,type="l",col="red", ylab = NULL, xlab = 'LogP',xaxt="n",yaxt="n" )
axis(2,ylim(c(min(DataOzono$Temperature),max(DataOzono$Temperature)), layout.widths(2)))
mtext(text = 'T',line = 2,side = 2)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(DataOzono$LogP, DataOzono$RH,type="l",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
axis(4)
mtext("RH",side=4,line=2)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(DataOzono$LogP, DataOzono$Ozone,type="l",col="green",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
mtext("O3",side=5,line=3)
axis(2, line = 4)
```

any advice will be very helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by subset? Do you want one chart (with 3 plots) for each number in the column file?

Comment: Also, are you using windows?

Comment: I think i didnt explain myself, i want to create a plot of those variables for every file code in the data frame. The chart is supossed to be like three y axis ( one per variable) and one x axis. and yes im using windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to plot the charts in a `loop`. In the example you gave, we only have one file number. However, it should create a chart for every number in the file column. On Windows, you can use `savePlot` to save to your drive. I simplified your example because I was getting errors.

```
DataOzono <- read.table(text="pressure    height  Temperature RH  Ozone   file    LogP
753.6   2541    16.8    76  0   80131   0.3475673
748.0   2604    17.7    32  0   80131   0.347959
743.5   2656    15.9    38  0   80131   0.3482766
739.8   2697    15.4    39  0   80131   0.3485396
736.6   2734    15.0    41  0   80131   0.3487685
731.8   2790    14.5    42  0   80131   0.3491142", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

original_par <- par()
par(mar=c(5.1, 8.1, 4.1, 3.1))

for (i in unique(DataOzono$file)){
DataOzono_subset <- DataOzono[DataOzono$file==i,] #keep only rows for that file number

plot(DataOzono_subset$LogP, DataOzono_subset$Temperature, axes= F,type="l",col="red", ylab = "", xlab = 'LogP',xaxt="n",yaxt="n" )
axis(2,col="red",col.axis="red")
mtext(text = 'T',line = 2,side = 2,col="red",col.lab="red")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(DataOzono_subset$LogP, DataOzono_subset$RH,type="l",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
axis(4,col="blue",col.axis="blue")
mtext("RH",side=4,line=2,col="blue",col.lab="blue" )
par(new=TRUE)
plot(DataOzono_subset$LogP, DataOzono_subset$Ozone,type="l",col="darkgreen",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
mtext("O3",side=2,line=6,,col="darkgreen",col.lab="darkgreen")
axis(2, line = 4,col="darkgreen",col.axis="darkgreen")

savePlot(filename=paste0("c:/temp/",i,".png"),type="png")
}

par()  <- original_par #restore par to initial value.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank very much this solves all my problems, just one question im getting this error "Error in savePlot(filename = paste0("c:/temp/", i, ".png"), type = "png") : 
  can only copy from 'windows' devices" 
It can be related to my working directory is not at :C but a partition :E?

Comment: Try changing the path ("c:/temp/") to a directory that already exists on your computer. Also make sure that programs can write to this folder. Usually c:/temp is a safe bet, that's why I chose this path. Also, if savePlot does not work, see the examples in '?png'. For this, you need to put the png line before the plot and dev.off() after the plot in your loop.

Comment: I didnt figured out why savePlot didnt work, i used the png function instead.